# Connecting to Raspberry Pi on Remote Network (XFinity Router)

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, raspberry-pi

I have set up a Raspberry Pi in my home office with a Linux OS and have installed Apache (PHP/MySQL). Everything is working and I've been able to successfully connect via SSH from my computer while connected to the same network in my home.

I've seen many similar questions on here but none that can outline what I'm trying to do. I have an XFinity Router and can access it's settings using IP 10.0.0.1 locally. I've read into Port Forwarding which I've set up for the Raspberry Pi but now I'm stuck on the next step in the settings to get it set up so I can connect to it remotely (from a network outside my home's). I'm hoping to use this to host web-based PHP scripts that we can run from any web browsers as well as be able to SSH in from any internet connection.

I'm sorry if this is similar to other questions here but the XFinity interface seems to trouble me and it's not making it easy for me to wrap my head around Port Forwarding and what goes into setting this up correctly.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do three things:

- Make sure your Raspberry Pi gets the same IP address on your LAN every time. This can be done by configuring your router for DHCP reservation by using the Pi's MAC (ethernet hardware address), if it supports it. To get the Pi's MAC, You can type `ipconfig eth0`, or you can use Advanced IP Scanner for Windows, or my own Pi Finder for Mac. (Alternatively, you can set your Pi to use a static IP address.)
- Forward port 22 (SSH) in your router to the internal IP address you chose. (If your router supports forwarding a different external address to internal port 22, I recommend doing that for extra security.)
- Get a consistent external IP address or name, so you can find your home network on the outside. If you don't have a static IP address from your ISP, then you will need a Dynamic DNS service, such as those offered from Dyn.com, no-ip.com, and Namecheap. You'll need to configure your router to update the service, and not all routers support all Dynamic DNS services (or any). (Alternatively, you can install a Dynamic DNS updater client on your Raspberry Pi or other computer on your home network, but that may or may not be easy.)

I can't advise specifics as to how to configure your particular router, but these three steps are what are generally required to do what you want, and the rest is figuring out the specifics of how your router wants it.

Comment: This is great. The main step I had to follow was #2. I had everything else set (and even had port forwarding set) but was forwarding the wrong port. Once I updated it to 22, everything worked. Thanks for your help!